# The changes to the database were committed successfully...The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, entity

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Unable to set field/property logins on entity type Evalv.Services.employedetail

Entity framework classes for login and employee

```
public partial class login
{
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string emailId { get; set; }
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
}

public partial class employedetail
{
    public employedetail()
    {
        this.logins = new HashSet<login>();
    }

    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }       
    public string emailId { get; set; }               

    public virtual ICollection<login> logins { get; set; }
}
```

**Method to Save data**

```
//employedetail e  and login l are entity objects with data passed to below method.

public string RegisterUser(employedetail e , login l)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (EvalvEntities context = new EvalvEntities())
                    {
                        context.employedetails.Add(e);
                        context.logins.Add(l);
                        if (context.SaveChanges() > 0)
                        {
                            return "Registered";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return "Not Registered";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Error :" + ex;
                }

            }
```

**Note** : Some other posts for same exception insisted this could be because of absense of primary keys. But I have primary key's & foreign key for both `employedetail` and `login` tables. So not sure what's going wrong. Should I call `context.SaveChanges()` every time we add entity object to context?

for example

```
context.employedetails.Add(e);
context.SaveChanges();
context.logins.Add(l);
context.SaveChanges();
```

or is there any better way to do this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** : On Logging the query generated for the context.savechanges() i got following query & Exception

```
INSERT [dbo].[employedetails]([employeeId], [firstName], [middleName], [lastName], [emailId])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, @2, @3, )
-- @0: '4567' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: 'sam' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @2: 'anderson' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @3: 'sam@gmail.com' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- Executing at 30-12-2016 12:17:27 AM +05:3
-- Completed in 1 ms with result: 1


INSERT [dbo].[login]([employeeId], [emailId], [password], [status], [active])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, @3)
-- @0: '4567' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: 'sam@gmail.com' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @2: '123456' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @3: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- Executing at 30-12-2016 12:17:28 AM +05:30
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: 1
```

**Exception thrown**: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

**Update 2** : Image with mappings for login
[image]

Comment: What's the *exact*  content of the login object `l` when you save it? Esp. the value of its `employeeId` is interesting.

Comment: @GertArnold some contents of login object l is derived from employedetails object.i.e - employedetails & login both  will have same **employeeId, emailId** during insertion.

Comment: `login` doesn't seem to have a primary key. Can you show the mappings?

Comment: Why do you have `emailId` in both entities? What if `login` has a different `emailId`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one to many relationship for login and EmployeeDetail class then you are missing `public virtual employedetail employeedetail {get; set;}` in login class.

Please add this line in your Login class.(Because of this you are getting this problem.)

```
public partial class login
{
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string emailId { get; set; }
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual employedetail employeedetail {get; set;} //Add this in your class
}
```

Note: - Class name first letter should be in Capital and correct the spelling of employedetail to EmployeeDetail in your class Name.

Comment: I already had the above suggested line (which i removed after sometime) but it didnt help.any other suggestions?

Comment: Then debug your code and check at add what query is generated.