# Entity Framework The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I'd like to understand why "The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state." exception occurs. 
I know that there are multiple threads related to similar issue but none seems to answer my question. (Closest to my problem is: [The changes to the database were committed successfully...The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381719/the-changes-to-the-database-were-committed-successfully-the-objectcontext-migh) )

I've got Database First model containing tables:

```
Training (PK Id)
User (PK Id)
UserTraining(PK (UserId, TrainingId), FK(UserId), FK(TrainingId))
Documentation(PK Id, FK TrainingId)
UserDocumentation (PK (UserId, TrainingId, DocumentationId),
    FK(UserId, TrainingId), FK(DocumentationId))
```

All above tables are properly mapped in code(all keys are present etc.).

What I'm doing is - Create Training with Documentation, then Create UserTraining with UserDocumentation, like below:

```
var type = this.trainingRepository.GetTrainingType(command.Training.TypeId);
var training = new Training(
    type,
    command.Training.Name,
    command.Training.Documentation,
    ...);


if (type.Equals(TrainingType.Mandatory))
{
    var users = this.userRepository.GetAllUsers();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        user.AssignTraining(training);//under the hood is created new instance of UserTraining with relation to training and UserDocumentation related to UserTraining and Documentation from training
    }
}

trainingRepository.Add(training);
trainingRepository.SaveChanges();
```

There are 2 repositories but each uses the same instance of DBContext(registered as PerRequest).

Now if I move adding and saving changes above **if (type.Equals(TrainingType.Mandatory))** and add one move SaveChanges at the end of method everything passes without any issues.

Unfortunately in case above it throws exception mentioned in title.
Now the question - Why does adding in the middle and then updating work and my solution doesn't? Can it be related to poor database schema or rather EF limitations?

AssignTraining method:

```
public void AssignTraining(Training training)
{
    this.State.UserTrainings.Add(new UserTraining(training));
}
```

UserTraining constructor:

```
public UserTraining(Training training) : base(new 
DataAccess.Database.UserTraining())
{
    this.State.Training = training;
    if(training.Documentation != null)
    {
        this.State.UserDocumentations.Add(new UserDocumentation(training.Documentation));
    }
}
```

Comment: what does AssignTraining do? Could you show its code?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro added details to the question.